# Stop words from breaking with CSS Hyphens Auto on

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I have a website where I use the `hyphens: auto` function to break longer words. It all works fine, but at some places it breaks words which shouldn't be broken. For example names of team members. How can I still keep the hyphens function, but exclude some words from breaking?
As it only happens on a very few words I could edit every word separately.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please kindly add minimal code snippet html and css

Comment: Try using a non-breaking hyphen &#8209; It works just like &nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no code example I am assuming that I understood it correctly.

I think putting these words into a span which you style accordingly should do the trick.

```
<div>
    <p>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>
        very long paragraph which doesn't end Edgar <span>TestingnamesonIdont'tknowwhatcanmakethispossiblyanylongerthanthiswhichIamdoingrightnow.</span>

    </p>
</div>

p{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;


    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}

p span{

    overflow-wrap: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    -ms-hyphens: none;
    -moz-hyphens: none;
    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
}
```

Hope this helped!